# (Win Server 2012 R2) Can't enable data deduplication

Tags: storage, windows-server-2012-r2, administration, deduplication, storage-spaces

Windows Server 2012 R2 (Datacentre edition)

I cannot enable Data Deduplication. This particular volume previously had data deduplication enabled. Computer was changed from BIOS to UEFI boot, so basically Windows was reinstalled and boot disk has changed. However I get the same error on new volumes that did not previously have it enabled.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Enable-DedupVolume E:
Enable-DedupVolume : MSFT_DedupVolume.Volume='E:' - HRESULT 0x80010108, The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-DedupVolume E:
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DedupVolume:ROOT/Microsoft/...SFT_DedupVolume) [Enable-DedupVolume], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Enable-DedupVolume
```

Or if using the GUI, I get the error:

```
There was an error updating Data Deduplication on volume: MSFT_DedupVolume.Volume='\\?\Volume{[guid removed]}\' - HRESULT 0x80004002, No such interface supported
```

Trying to manually start the services gives this:

```
Windows could not start the Data Deduplication Service on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code -2141826298.
```

and

```
The Data Deduplication Service service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
2147483647
```

Comment: I have run chkdsk, no problems found, also did a sfc /scannow. It appears I cannot run any dedup tasks, I get the same (or similar) errors. It seems the service itself won't start.

Comment: The drives are mirrored dynamic disks. Some were present in the old system and had deduplication enabled. Some are new from this system.

The operating system from the old system (same physical server, but changed to UEFI so had to reinstall OS) was copied to the new system and the boot process recreated using UEFI instead of BIOS.

Some part of this process has caused this error. However, reinstalling the Hyper-V and Deduplication features has corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I removed and re-added the Hyper-V and Data Deduplication roles/features, and this seems to have corrected the issue.

I am not sure why or what happened, but I believe some settings or configuration from the old operating system prior to it being moved from BIOS/MBR to UEFI/GPT must have been causing issues.

Comment: I spoke too soon.

It appears the reboot probably "fixed" it, nothing to do with re-adding the roles.

I have a recovery partition (which I manually created using diskpart), which is mapped to drive N. This annoys me, so I remove the drive letter to hide the partition. This breaks data deduplication.

When I reboot drive N comes back even after I have removed it.

Remove the drive letter, deduplication breaks.

Add the drive letter back, deduplication starts to work again.

I suspect there is something wrong here, but for the time being, at least I know what is breaking it.